# Compare two columns and leave only the values that don't match

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, duplicates, flatten

Question is pretty self explanatory. I have two columns (num1, num2) and I just want to return the values that do not match (and not the others):

[image]

So the ideal return is simply 2,3,4,5

Edited for clarity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(A2:B), COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(A2:B), FLATTEN(A2:B))=1)
```

[image]

or if you want it sorted:

```
=SORT(FILTER(FLATTEN(A2:B), COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(A2:B), FLATTEN(A2:B))=1))
```

or if you want it joint:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, SORT(FILTER(FLATTEN(A2:B), COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(A2:B), FLATTEN(A2:B))=1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the optional [exactly once] argument of UNIQUE to achieve the same thing in this particular context:

```
=unique(flatten(A2:B),,1)
```

This can then be sorted/joined if required.

Comment: unique with flatten wont filter out duplicates

Comment: If there are duplicates within each column, then you could just do a standard UNIQUE on each column (i.e. return distinct values), combine them as a column in an array literal and then do a UNIQUE [exactly once] on the outside: =unique({unique(A2:A);unique(B2:B)},,1)